# How to format Java console output?

Tags: java

I have been working on a Simple Console Application, which lets to build your own PC.
In the end, It prints your receipt which lists all the parts you choose

This is the Output I'm getting

[image: This is the Output I'm getting]

The Code for the output above.

```
public static void printReceipt() {
        System.out.println("=================================");
        System.out.println("          Your Receipt           ");
        System.out.println("=================================");

        System.out.println("1) " + mbName + "             " + mbPrice);
        System.out.println("2) " + proName + "             " + proPrice);
        System.out.println("8) " + gpuName + "             " + gpuPrice);
        System.out.println("3) " + ramName + "             " + ramPrice);
        System.out.println("4) " + stoName + "             " + stoPrice);
        System.out.println("5) " + coolName + "             " + coolPrice);
        System.out.println("6) " + psuName + "             " + psuPrice);
        System.out.println("7) " + cabName + "             " + cabPrice);

        double total = subtotal(mbPrice, proPrice, ramPrice, stoPrice, coolPrice, psuPrice, cabPrice, gpuPrice);

        System.out.println("=================================");
        System.out.println("GRAND TOTAL:       " + total + "/-");
        System.out.println("=================================");

        System.out.println(" =================================");
        System.out.println("|            Thank you            |");
        System.out.println(" =================================");

    }
```

Is there a way to format the output above into something like shown below?

```
=================================
          Your Receipt           
=================================

  Item                   Price
 ------                 -------

1) Asus                  20000.0
2) INTEL                 45000.0
8) Nvidia gtx 1050ti     17000.0
3) Asus                  18000.0
4) Samsung               20000.0
5) Coolermaster          20000.0
6) Ortis                  4000.0
7) Asus                   4000.0
=================================
GRAND TOTAL:            148000.0/-
=================================
```

Comment: Cant reach the image. could you post it another way or share the output?

Comment: You can try String.format with padding. See for example here https://www.developer.com/java/java-string-format-method/